# Android rx call multiples sentences in sequence

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

stack overflow community, I am just starting with responsive programming rx, and I have the following code block in which in summary I have an insert with ROOM, with the generated id I save this information through a REST service with retrofit, if the service Answer that it was saved correctly, I update the registry successfully. Until now I have this code but I think it is very ugly in addition to the nests it generates.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Best regards

```
        acta.setStatus(0);
        disposable.add( actaDataSource.insert( acta )//Call insert row DAO with ROOM and return Single<Long>
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Long id) {
                    acta.setId( id );
                    mOcrRepository.putActa( acta )//Call service rest with retrofit for save data in server
                            .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
                            .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() )
                            .subscribeWith( new DisposableSingleObserver<ActaResponse>(){
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(ActaResponse actaResponse) {
                                    if( actaResponse.isSuccess() ){
                                        acta.setStatus(1);
                                        actaDataSource.update( acta )//Call update row DAO with ROOM and return Completable
                                                .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() )
                                                .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() )
                                                .subscribeWith(new CompletableObserver() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete() {
                                                        //Return three steps succes complete
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                                        //Return three steps failed
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }else{
                                        //Return one step success complete and two step failed

                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    //Return one step success complete and two step failed
                                }
                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //Return all  failed
                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatmap` operator can help you clean your code and make it look like simple.

Comment: Hi Leo, The new observable that comes out of the flatMap doesn’t guarantee you the same order. The values are interleaved and I need same order. :(

Comment: Ah, you can use `concatMap` to ensure the order.